# How to identity Page Not Found route in root component [ Angular 2 ]?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on a sample Angular 2 application which also has  routing feature, and below is my routing related code.

```
....
...
RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', component: LoginComponent },          
        { path: "spa/home", canActivate: [canActivateGuard], component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'spa/about', canActivate: [canActivateGuard],  component: AboutComponent },
        { path: 'spa/login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
    ])
....
....
```

In my root component , based on current route , it needs to set value of "blnDisplayMenu" to true or false. 
Below code in root component sets "blnDisplayMenu" to false if current route is '/spa/login'.

```
ngOnInit() {  

    this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
        if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            if (e.url == '/' || e.url == '/spa/login') {                   
                this.blnDisplayMenu = false;
            }
            else {                    
                this.blnDisplayMenu = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My question is how to set "blnDisplayMenu" to false even when current route is "**".

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add more details over conditions when you want your blnDisplayMenu true/false. Based on limited information, here is what I can think of:
Try to make two conditions.
1) Where you want to make your blnDisplayMenu true
2) Where you want to make your blnDisplayMenu false

I am just putting a sample based on above code assuming these two routes(spa/about and spa/home) you want to have blnDisplayMenu as true.

As "**" represents any route so if you have covered all the routs where you want to make blnDisplayMenu true then rest all will automatically be covered in else clause.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
        if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            if (e.url == '/spa/about' || e.url == '/spa/home') { // add any other route where you want blnDisplayMenu = true
                this.blnDisplayMenu = true;
            }else{
                this.blnDisplayMenu = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With usage of `NavigationEnd` and from its url you have to compare all your valid url and need to set `blnDisplayMenu` value to `true` or `false` but comparing all the route is not good way so you can use `data` option of route configuration.

Set one flag say `displayMenu` as data on route for `**` as below :

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },          
  { path: "spa/home", canActivate: [canActivateGuard], component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'spa/about', canActivate: [canActivateGuard],  component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'spa/login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, data : { displayMenu: false } }
])
......
```

Then use [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html) in your component to check if `displayMenu` variable is there or not on your `ActivatedRoute`.

```
@Component()
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obs = this.route
      .data
      .subscribe(v => {
        if(v.displayMenu === false) {
          this.blnDisplayMenu = false;
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.obs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: but how to set to "true" for other routes ?

Comment: got it , in else

Comment: one solution is to use `NavigationEnd` for other routes and `ActivatedRoute` for `**` route but i am not sure if its execution sequence will affect the output or not[may be overwrite `blnDisplayMenu` value ] and 2nd solution is to set `displayMenu` to `true` on all other route and in `ActivatedRoute`'s else part set `blnDisplayMenu` to `true`.

Comment: also if you do not set `displayMenu` on all other route then you will get `v.displayMenu` equal to `undefined` inside `subscribe` method of `ActivatedRoute` so you can check by setting `if(v.displayMenu === undefined) { this.blnDisplayMenu = true; }`

Comment: I think this solution will work only when "data" is set for all routes , because subscribe will execute only when "data" is set